# Declared User Agent being overridden

Tags: windows-8, browser, user-agent

I have an old Microsoft Surface 2 (released back in 2013), ARM32 on Windows 8.1 RT. I need to change my User Agent string so to have sites show me their non-tablet version. Would be a cinch for other browsers, but I'm stuck with Internet Explorer 11 as the browser, due to Microsoft locking this device down.

If you suggest I purchase a new device, I simply refuse to.

So, I'll just resort to changing my User Agent. There's this helpful question from this very site, [Internet Explorer: Editing User Agent String so it is Seen By the Server](https://superuser.com/questions/925817/internet-explorer-editing-user-agent-string-so-it-is-seen-by-the-server). This is the original User Agent that appears,

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

With the first key\string,
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\User Agent\Version`,
I had to add the new key `User Agent` & then the new string `Version`. Now I tried this new string (not pretending I fully understand the syntax, nor is it correct)

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; ARM) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome`.

I then restart IE to find that my new User agent is:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; ARM) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome; Windows NT 6.3; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

My supposedly declared User Agent gets appended with other tags I know not were from & then wrapped in parentheses by the Mozilla tag.

There is another key/string mentioned in the question located at, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent\Version`.
I had to add the new string `Version`. This had the exact same effect, from the point of view of my browser. From the question referenced by the link, this second key affects the DOM for the browser, whereas the first one is more on the HTTP component of Windows

So what's going on? How do I get my intended User Agent appear? Seems to me there's still a higher function somewhere that adds more tags & wraps what's on the key. Any idea where that is? Or, some switch to turn it off?

Comment: Assuming this is really IE11, have you tried using `about:flags` in the address bar and seeing if you can set a custom user agent string there rather than messing with the registry?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for that, here is your answer with multiple options.

- First "it seems" this is impossible. I tried myself and searched everywhere and found people who were also trying with no luck. I say "it seems" because I haven't read a reason on this being 100% impossible, but I (we) couldn't find a single way to get it done. There are tricks to achieve this on Windows (x86) but none of them work with Windows RT.
- Upgrade to Windows 10 (yes, Surface RT). A while ago a Windows 10 version leaked and many enthusiasts have worked hard on it and now it's possible to install Windows 10 on the Surface RT 1 and 2, that is Windows on ARM (32). The benefit of this is you can install many apps and you get Microsoft Edge, it works way better than IE. It's an old version of IE because it was never upgraded and there is no way to get a more recent version, but hey, it's something!

The process to install W10 is not simple, it's a bit technical. I'm not sure if a direct link here would be wise so go ahead and search for "install windows 10 for arm32 on you surface rt" and take your time to read, eventually you will find some links are better than others leading you to final instructions how to do it (there are several tutorials).

Windows 10 for ARM leaked to the public, so it's not a good idea to just send links I guess. Good luck, and yes, it works way better than the original Windows version on the RT.